# Woocommerce add to cart url with quantity?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can hard code an add to cart url, it works just fine.

```
<a href="' . get_home_url() . '/product/myproduct/?add-to-cart=101">Add to cart</a>
```

However, I'd like to know if I can add the quantity to this query string? Say, like:

```
<a href="' . get_home_url() . '/product/myproduct/?add-to-cart=101&quantity=2">Add to cart</a>
```

Is this even possible and I just don't know the right query string word for quantity? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, `quantity` will work, and you can use any base url (home for example), then, by default it will redirect to your cart page.

```
<a href="' . get_home_url() . '?add-to-cart=101&quantity=2">Add to cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

But with the ajax call "get_refreshed_fragments" its double the quantity